# How to filter an array of numbers using different intervals?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

In the example code below I want to filter numbersArray based on different intervals. An interval is defined by a combination of 2 arrays with the lower and upper bound of said interval. How do I identify matches or non-matches like below?

```
const numbersArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
const lowerBound = [1, 4, 8];
const higherBound = [3, 6, 10];
```

If the code works the following test should return true:

```
matches == [2, 5, 9];
nonmatches == [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10];
```

**Assume the arrays contains more than 1000 items and that the numbers doesn't follow any pattern.**

Below is a less readable but more realistic scenario.

```
let numbersArray = [];
let lowerBound = [];
let higherBound = [];

for (let i = 0; i< 1000; i++){
  numbersArray.push(i);
}

for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  lowerBound.push(i * 10);
  higherBound.push((i * 10) + Math.random() * 10);
}
```

Comment: . Do you want to find a way to compare the differences or the matches between lowerBound and higherBound?

Comment: Will the bound arrays always be the same length? Do they deal with -Infinity +Infiity? How much do you care about performance?

Comment: It will always be an interval we are looking for. Therefore, if the arrays are of different length it would be an error. An interval is the combination of a certain index for example `lowerBound[index]` to `higherBound[index]`.

Regarding performance: It should be fast enough for no visible delay in UI. So at max 10ms and the lower the better.

Comment: I tried to understand your problem statement about what an interval is, how the bounds relate to the interval, and what the intended behavior between the interval and the numbersArray should be. But I honestly can't understand it, I think the problem is insufficiently defined and has readers guessing what the intend behavior is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm going to assume that we can change the data structure a little bit because this is quite awkward to work with:

```js
const lowerBound = [1, 4, 8];
const higherBound = [3, 6, 10];
```

If the elements at the same indexes are meant to be together then let's just do that:

```js
const bound = [[1, 3], [4, 6], [8, 10]];
```

Will come to `bound` later.

Now let's build a curried function that validates `n` if `a < n && n < b`:

```js
const between = (a, b) => n => a < n && n < b;

const x = between(1, 3);
const y = between(4, 6);

x(1); // false
x(2); // true
y(1); // false
y(5); // true
```

Now let's build another curried function that validates `n` if at least one function returns `true`:

```js
const or = (...fns) => n => fns.some(fn => fn(n));

const check = or(x, y);

check(1); // false
check(2); // true
check(5); // true
```

We will now transform `bound` into an *or* function after we transformed each pair into a *between* function:

```js
const bound = [[1, 3], [4, 6], [8, 10]];
const check = or(...bound.map(([a, b]) => between(a, b)));
```

`check` is now a function that takes an `n` and returns `true` if `n` is between 1 and 3 or between 4 and 6, ...

```js
const between = (a, b) => n => a < n && n < b;
const or = (...fns) => n => fns.some(fn => fn(n));

const bound = [[1, 3], [4, 6], [8, 10]];
const check = or(...bound.map(([a, b]) => between(a, b)));

const [nomatch, match] =
  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].reduce(
    (acc, n) =>
      (acc[+check(n)].push(n), acc),
        [[], []]);

console.log(`match: [${match}]`);
console.log(`no match: [${nomatch}]`);
```

Comment: I agree with the predicates, and definitely with the awkwardness of the datastructure that  just raises a lot of questions. Nice work on the structuring of the different methods :)

Comment: `.reduce((results, n) => (results[+check(n)].push(n), results), [[],[]])` would be the compact version of `reduce` in the final snippet. (It does swap the resulting `match` and `nomatch`.)

Comment: This is a very readable solution, and very convenient combined with @3limin4t0r s zip-solution for the awkward data structure. 
This is the by far fastest solution for the provided test data and also separates the concerns in a nice way.

Answer (score 6):

I think I would extract the lowerbound and upperbound values first into a list of predicates, and then just iterate those per number in the array. Depending if one matches, it either goes into the match result or the non-match result.

```js
function filtered( array, lower, upper) {
  const predicates = lower.map( (v, i) => (value) => value > v && value < upper[i] );
  return array.reduce( (agg, cur) => {
    if (predicates.some( predicate => predicate(cur) )) {
      agg[0].push(cur);
    } else {
      agg[1].push(cur);
    }
    return agg;
  }, [[],[]]);
}

function simpleTest() {
  const numbersArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
  const lowerBound = [1, 4, 8];
  const higherBound = [3, 6, 10];

  const [matches, nonmatches] = filtered( numbersArray, lowerBound, higherBound );

  console.log( 'matches' );
  console.log( matches );
  console.log( 'matches' );
  console.log( nonmatches );
}

function suggestedTest() {
  // with suggested test
  let numbersArray = [];
  let lowerBound = [];
  let higherBound = []
  for (let i = 0; i< 1000; i++){
    numbersArray.push(i);
  }
  for(let i=0;i<100;i++) {
    lowerBound.push(i*10);
    higherBound.push((i*10)+Math.random()*10);
  }

  const [matches, nonmatches] = filtered( numbersArray, lowerBound, higherBound );
  console.log( 'matches' );
  console.log( matches );
  console.log( 'matches' );
  console.log( nonmatches );
}

console.log('basic');
simpleTest();

console.log('suggested');
suggestedTest();
```

Personally, I would also check if the lowerbound & upperbound arrays have the same length, but the question doesn't seem to define a behavior for this scenario. I'm also not sure what should happen in case of overlapping ranges, but these are all not specified

Answer (score 5):

Tweaked my approach slightly to avoid the second filter loop. It's just a case of testing each number in the array against the implicit pair of `lowerBound` and `higherBound`. You can utilise the iteration variable in [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to achieve this quite concisely, assuming the arrays have been properly formatted beforehand and there are no loose ends.

```js
const numbersArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
const lowerBound = [1, 4, 8];
const higherBound = [3, 6, 10];

let matches = [];
let nonMatches = [];
  
numbersArray.forEach(num => {
  const matched = lowerBound.some((bound, i) => {
    return num > bound && num < higherBound[i];
  });

  matched ? matches.push(num) : nonMatches.push(num);
});

console.log(matches, nonMatches);
```

Comment: Any reason you didn't go for `reduce`? It seems more natural to use `reduce` over a `forEach` when it results in data after the `forEach` loop

Comment: I tend to [avoid reduce](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=qaGjS7-qWzg) these days unless I'm doing exactly what it says on the tin (i.e *reducing* an iterable to a single value/array/object). None of the data here has actually changed so I don't think it's a good use case.

Answer (score 5):

This approach is pretty straight forward. First zip `lowerBound` and `higherBound` together for convenience (this is optional). Then for each `number` in `numbersArray`, check if there is at least one match (using [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)) between a lower and higher bound. Add the number to the "match" or "non-match" array.

```js
const numbersArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
const lowerBound = [1, 4, 8];
const higherBound = [3, 6, 10];

// zip the lower and higher bounds together
const bounds = lowerBound.map((_, i) => [lowerBound[i], higherBound[i]]);

const result = {true: [], false: []};
for (const number of numbersArray) {
  const match = bounds.some(([low, high]) => low < number && number < high);
  result[match].push(number);
}

console.log("matches:", ...result[true]);
console.log("non-matches:", ...result[false]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Is that what you want ?

I'm using reduce to create an array of matches where I put a new element when this one matches (between lowerBound and higherBound) and for the nonmatches, just a filter of the numbers in numbersArray which are not presents in matches.

```js
const numbersArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
const lowerBound = [1, 4, 8];
const higherBound = [3, 6, 10];

const matches = lowerBound.reduce((acc, val, i) => {
  return [
    ...acc,
    ...numbersArray.filter(o => !acc.includes(o) && o > lowerBound[i] && o < higherBound[i])
    ]
}, []);

const nonmatches = numbersArray.filter(o => !matches.includes(o));
console.log(matches);
console.log(nonmatches);
```

Comment: Bearing in mind this prouduces duplicates in the `matched` array when the bounds overlap.

Comment: Note that this answer does have to iterate 3 times through `numbersArray` for this example. Or generalized: it need to iterate N times through `numbersArray`, where N is the length of the `lowerBound` (or `higherBound`) array.